# How to transform a LinkedHashMap Payload to Object Payload in mule?

Tags: object, hashmap, mule, transform, payload

I want to transform a `LinkedHashMap` Payload to `Object` Payload in mule , i used the Byte Array to Object transformer but it dosent work for me , any idea guys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to mention specifically the Object type. A LinkedHashMap is already an instance of Object: every Java instances inherit from the root class Object.

If you want to transform your HashMap into a specific object such as JSON or a custom object such as com.mycompany.CompData, you have several possibilities depending on your use case:

- use DataWeave as mentioned in other answers (require EE)
- use a built-in transformer such as Object-to-JSON
- implement your own Transformer by extending AbstractTransformer

Se the docs for details: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/using-transformers

If you may be more specific as to what your use case is I'll gladly refine my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can use dataweave to transform a payload of generic type (=`java.util.Map`) to a specific type (`foo.bar.Type` in the example):

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload as :object {
    class: "foo.bar.Type"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either dataweave or json to object transformer.